# Named Values Excel Lookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet containing named values of football clubs in the leftmost column and named column titles across the top.

How can I insert the value from a certain cell in another sheet?

For example, I want to insert Aston Villa's Ranking of TE in a cell on another worksheet. Is this possible and how can I do it?

Also, If I have a list of the same names i.e Aston Villa on the separate worksheet, can I have drag down to automatically fill the values based on the name of the club in the same worksheet?

[image: enter image description here]]

Answer (score 1):

I have taken this dummy data as an example.

```
| Club       | Transfer Summer | Transfer Winter | Average |
|------------|-----------------|-----------------|---------|
| Aston      | 23              | 23              | 94      |
| Birmingham | 32              | 29              | 53      |
| Bolton     | 96              | 72              | 80      |
```

1. Name the range.

Select all your data then click Formulas > Name Manager > New. I called my example range "football"

2. Enter your VLOOKUP

To look up the Transfer Winter number for Birmingham, we would use this formula;

```
=VLOOKUP("Birmingham",football,3,FALSE)
```

This would return 29.

VLOOKUP needs to know

- what it is looking for
- the range of cells to look in
- which column to return
- whether to use a range lookup, usually FALSE

If you had a list of clubs in the A col of another sheet, you could also do;

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,football,3,FALSE)
```

This would allow you to drag down and get the values for those clubs.

Comment: Thanks to bertieb for making my formatting a bit clearer :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)